# How to create style sheet for creating html preview

Tags: c++, winapi, dom, html-parsing

I am developing a visual c++ Win-API application and I want to create a style sheet to display the html contents(I am not sure that i need to create style sheet only may be some thing else.But want to know what else can be used instead ?). Any idea how to achieve that??.Is it the same procedure as is the case with XML style sheet creation ?? (in xml file case we create a style sheet in order to preview on preview-pane)

If not please give idea how to do that ? As in case of html file we also have to take in account the font colour/background colour/font sizes etc. How to do that ?
(Actually i  have to create preview handler for .html file) I have done every thing i just need to create style sheet (If not style sheet then some thing like this which will help me to display the html contents) and i already have data of .html file in a stream (which is IStreal * FinalHTMLStream)I just need to find the mechanism (like cretaing style sheet or may be any other)to create the html preview on preview pane using this stream.

Any Idea how to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

There are certain frameworks that allow you to create an HTML control easily, [Win32++](http://win32-framework.sourceforge.net/) is one of them. Give it a try.

Comment: but i am using x64 with visual c++ (not win32)

Comment: @ShekharSinghSHEKHAWAT search mCtrl it has support for both 32 and 64bit.

Comment: don't you think that it can be achieved using IHTMLDocument2 interface in visual c++ ??? What do you say ??